# Setting oninput event with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom-events

The HTML5 `oninput` event is supported by some modern browsers, including Firefox 3.X

However, strangely, it only seems to work with inline JavaScript:

```
<input id = "q" oninput="alert('blah')">
```

When I try to set it using JavaScript code, it doesn't fire.

```
var q = document.getElementById("q");
q.oninput = function(){alert("blah");};
```

Is this just a bug in Firefox, or is there some reason this happens?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in perhaps older versions of FF as it works for me in current version of both Chrome and FF. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/c5ywv/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After downloading FireFox v3.6.27 and doing some test and search. I found my previous answer was wrong.

What I got is:

> the oninput event property is supported in Firefox from version 4.

So to add a event listener in this case, you can do either

```
<input id = "q" oninput="alert('blah')">
```

or

```
q.addEventListener('input', function(){alert("blah");}, true);
```

But I prefer the later way. You can find reasons in [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F).
Also a similar function in IE [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).