# Remove unwanted characters from text input before they appear

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a function that limits a text input:

```
function alphaNumericSpace(inInput) {
    inInput.value = inInput.value.replace(/[^\w ]/g, "").replace(/^ +|( ) +/g, "$1");
}
```

Here is an example of a text input using it:

```
<input name="type" type="text" maxlength="32" onkeyup="alphaNumericSpace(this);">
```

The idea is to allow a user to be aware of the kind of text purging that will happen as they input it (only alphanumeric characters with a single space are allowed, the final whitespace at the end - if any - is removed in PHP).

However this has two problems that I would like to resolve:

- It is possible to hold down a key of an unwanted character to avoid
  the `onkeyup` event and click "Submit" at the same time. This causes
  unwanted characters to be submitted
- I don't want the unwanted characters to even appear in the text input
  in the first place, can they be rejected before being visible in the
  browser?

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery and http://api.jquery.com/change/ ?

Comment: I would rather not use jQuery, the site does not use it and I'd rather not introduce it to solve this. I'm sure that if it can be done in jQuery then it can be done in JavaScript. That being said, I don't care about Internet Explorer or really old browsers if it matters, it isn't relevant to this site

Comment: Then maybe you can try the `onInput` attribute on the input element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355499/setting-oninput-event-with-javascript

Comment: @AVP, I didn't know about that event, it seems to do what I want (it even catches copy / paste). If you make it an answer I will accept it

Comment: Why does it matter, clientside validation like this is just to enhance the user experience, you should wash the data on the serverside as well, so it shouldn't matter if invalid characters are submitted if someone goes out of their way to circumvent the validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `onInput` event.

```
<input oninput="alert('hello')">
```

Reference: [setting oninput event with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355499/setting-oninput-event-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't disable the bad characters showing up, the user may not find that friendly but that is sort of a subjective opinion.

It shouldn't be a problem they can submit bad data. You can never trust data coming from the browser to your server. They can always disable javascript etc

If, for usability purposes you don't want that submit to happen you can do something like this.

*Edit: no jquery... sorry about that but you can use*
[FormOnSubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp)

```
<from id="myid" onsubmit="formsubmit"
function formsubmit () {
        e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the submit.
        // Check for good data
        // if good submit, else reject the submit
 });
```

*If you really don't want them to show up `keydown` should work for you*

Comment: The OP would prefer not to use jQuery.

Comment: Updated. to fix that, didn't see that.